Observing if a script has loaded using a MutationObserver?
In this Lit Element demo I'm trying to check whether a script element has loaded with a callback like this (It's not correct and I'll also explain why).
  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();

    const hljs: HTMLScriptElement | null = document.querySelector(
      `script[src="${highlightCore()}"]`
    );
    if (hljs) {
      hljs.addEventListener(
        'onload',
        function (event: any) {
          console.log(`Highlighter.js script loaded`);
          if (event.target.nodeName === 'SCRIPT') {
            console.log('Script loaded: ' + event.target.getAttribute('src'));
          }
        },
        true
      );
    }
  }

And this does not work and if I understand correctly the reason is that the callback onload handler has to be added before the src attribute is set as indicated by this linked answer.
Also if we look in the developer console this error is produced.
[Deprecation] Listener added for a synchronous 'DOMNodeInserted' DOM Mutation Event. This event type is deprecated (https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#legacy-event-types) and work is underway to remove it from this browser. Usage of this event listener will cause performance issues today, and represents a risk of future incompatibility. Consider using MutationObserver instead.

Is there a way to use a MutationObserver to listen for onload events from script tags.
I need the event to fire even if the script has already loaded.

I'm not sure that synchronous DOMNodeInserted DOM Mutation Event the error is talking about is the onload event you're adding. I think it's more likely how lit adds the connectedCallback event. I doubt a MutationObserver is going to be any good in finding out if a script has loaded.

If it has any immediate effect, e.g. defining a global, check for that [global] to determine whether it loaded before you attached the event listener.

You could also add the script element dynamically, in which case you can add the only before you add it to the DOM. But there are other caveats to that, of course.

@HereticMonkey yes I was thinking about doing that.  Just creating the script elements myself and adding them dynamically, and listening for the load to be executed, but I was hoping that perhaps there was a way around this, since that would allow element users to declare async scripts outside of of the web component, and thus the web component could have it's modules loaded before it is initialized ...

You can override HTMLScriptElement.prototype's src setter using Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor and Object.defineProperty. Your override would add a listener before calling the original src setter.

@wOxxOm: Not sure how that would help with this, since being able to do that early enough would imply being able to attach an onload listener.

It depends on the overall setup, which we don't see, but one popular case is that the script element is created by another script (third-party).

The event to listen to is not onload, but load.
